# EF7 and GroupBy() cannot be translated

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have following code running on EF7 Beta 8:

```
var locationGrops = from l in db.Locations
                    group l by l.ServiceType into g
                    select g;

var list = locationGrops.ToList();
```

When I execute this code, EF displays a warning.

```
warning : [Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.QueryCompilationContext] The LINQ express
ion 'GroupBy([l].ServiceType, [l])' could not be translated and will be evaluate
d locally.
```

The query seems quite basic to me and there is GROUP BY in SQL. Is there any way to make it run on a server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this time `group by` and and most subqueries are not supported by EF7.

Comment: the same is in 7.0.0-rc1-final ;/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `context.Locations.FromSql(sql).ToList()` to ensure your query is run as you desire on the server.

Answer (score -1):

One approach is to create a database View with the logic (which for complex groupings is probably better anyway).

Right now it's a bit of a hack to use the view, but here's what I came up with if you're using scaffolding :

[How can I create database Views in a scaffolded DbContext in EF7 / Entity Framework Core 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37473450/how-can-i-create-database-views-in-a-scaffolded-dbcontext-in-ef7-entity-framew/)

In summary I inherit from the DbContext, and manually create the entity class for the view.